# OpenCL enqueTask vs enqueNDRangeKernel

Tags: c++, opencl

I'm writing OpenCL using the c++ bindings, trying to make a small library.

```
NDRange offset(0);
NDRange global_size(numWorkItems);
NDRange local_size(1);

//this call fails with error code -56
err = queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernelReduction, offset, global_size, local_size);
//this call works:
err = queue.enqueueTask(kernelReduction);
```

Now, Error code -56 is CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET. And I have no clue why the first call would fail. Any suggestions?

Comment: What dimension are you using? According to the OpenCL documentation offset needs to be an array of integer offsets, each corresponding to a specific dimension, but your code is not saying how many dimensions it's using.

Comment: As far as I understand by the c++ bindings, it's given by the NDRange initializer. Given 1 integer it'll assume 1 dimension, given 2 it'll assume 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using OpenCL 1.0, you cannot use global offsets afaik (you need to work around by using a constant memory counter or something). Try updating the bindings to OpenCL 1.1 if they don't automatically adapt and make sure you update your drivers as well.

Answer (score 1):

global_work_offset must be NULL. Any value here should produce CL_INVALID_GLOBAL_OFFSET.

check it out: [clEnqueueNDRangeKernel](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueNDRangeKernel.html)

Comment: You're looking at the OpenCL 1.0 documentation, in which global offsets were indeed not implemented and had to be null. This is not true for OpenCL 1.1 and 1.2 (where global offsets are working).

Comment: The question didn't specify the version, so this is my best guess.